# Can person on restricted list see if I add new friends?

Tags: facebook

If someone is on my restricted list, can they see if I add new friends and who they are?

Answer (score 1):

The "Restricted" list is used primarily to be friends with people you'd rather not be friends with. Friends on the "Restricted" list may only see your Public updates, like people who are not your friends. So if you do not make your friends list visible to "Public" then restricted friends cannot see your friend list activity, such as adding new friends.